# Xamarin forms Behaviors Input Validation With Error Labels

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm working on a project that uses a lot of User Inputs.
I have an input screen like this
[image: before validation]

but i want to use behaviors to show labels with error messages like this
[image: after validation]

I've managed to achieve this without behaviors but it took a lot of code,
so I want to use behaviors to have more of a clean robust code.
I've watched a lot of tutorials that changes the entry text or color,
but as I mentioned above I'm trying to have error labels.
am not even sure that is possible or not.

Updated
@ToolmakerSteve
I didn't try anything yet because I have no idea how to achieve this using View Model and data binding with data trigger.
I'm making this using another approach with a lot of messy code.
and my xaml looks like this

```
            <!--Name-->
            <Entry
                Placeholder="{xct:Translate Name}"
                Text="{Binding Name}"
                Style="{StaticResource EntryStyle}"/>
            <!--Name Error-->
            <Label
                Text="{Binding NameError}"
                Style="{StaticResource ErrorLabel}"
                IsVisible="{Binding NameErrorVisibility}"
                />

            <!--Email-->
            <Entry
                Placeholder="{xct:Translate Email}"
                Text="{Binding Email}"
                Style="{StaticResource EntryStyle}"/>
            <!--Email Error-->
            <Label
                Style="{StaticResource ErrorLabel}"
                Text="{Binding EmailError}"
                IsVisible="{Binding EmailErrorVisibility}"
                />

            <!--Password-->
            <Entry
                Placeholder="{xct:Translate Password}"
                Text="{Binding Password}"
                Style="{StaticResource EntryStyle}"/>
            <!--Password Error-->
            <Label
                Style="{StaticResource ErrorLabel}"
                Text="{Binding PasswordError}"
                IsVisible="{Binding PasswordErrorVisibility}"
                />

            <!--Confirmed Password-->
            <Entry
                Placeholder="{xct:Translate ConfirmedPassword}"
                Text="{Binding ConfirmedPass}"
                Style="{StaticResource EntryStyle}"/>
            <!--Confirmed Password Error-->
            <Label
                Style="{StaticResource ErrorLabel}"
                Text="{Binding ConfirmedPassError}"
                IsVisible="{Binding ConfirmedPassErrorVisibility}"
                />
```

Comment: Its easier to help if you show the XAML of one of the inputs (e.g. Name), and its corresponding validation error label, and your current code that you seek to simplify. One approach is a [Data Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/triggers#data-triggers). Have it set `IsVisible` on the error label. Put the XAML on the error label, and use `Binding="{Binding Source={...}, Path=...}"` to refer to entry. See also [XamGirl's Understanding Triggers](https://xamgirl.com/understanding-triggers-in-xamarin-forms/).

Comment: OR have a `BindableProperty` bool ShowNameError. Have your validation logic do  `ShowNameError = true;` Have error label do `<Label Text="My Error Message" IsVisible={Binding ShowNameError }`. See Data Binding docs and examples.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve
that's actually what am trying to do specially when using a view Model.
but am not able to manipulate this bindings in the way I need, have you any example that uses View Model.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: SO works best if **you show the code you tried**. Otherwise, any advice someone attempts to give may be a waste of their time. Its much clearer exactly the help you need, after seeing the code you have now. AND it makes the Q&A useful to FUTURE PEOPLE with a similar question - not just you. That's what makes SO such a great resource for everyone. Please edit your question with more details, as per the first sentence of my first comment. Then I'll be back to take a look. Thanks.

Comment: Also, show the code for the view model you have now. Given the view model code, and the XAML for your "email" widget, and your "email is required" widget, then I can easily show what you need to change or add. Also, read the link in Zhang's answer - the section "IsValid – BindableProperty".  We'll be copying that into a BindableProperty in the view model. (I'll figure out the exact details, once I see your current code.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar functionality of email,you can refer to the following code:

```
  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>

      <Style x:Key="baseStyle"
             TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="XAlign" Value="Start" />
        <Setter Property="YAlign" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Micro" />
        <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Italic" />
      </Style>
      <local:BooleanToObjectConverter x:Key="boolToStyleEmail"
                                           x:TypeArguments="Style">
        <local:BooleanToObjectConverter.FalseObject>
           <Style TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource baseStyle}">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#F44336" />
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="Enter a valid email" />
          </Style>
        </local:BooleanToObjectConverter.FalseObject>
        
        <local:BooleanToObjectConverter.TrueObject>
          <Style TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource baseStyle}">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#4CAF50" />
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="Your email looks good" />
          </Style>
        </local:BooleanToObjectConverter.TrueObject>

      </local:BooleanToObjectConverter>

    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>
  <StackLayout>
    <Grid>

      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />

      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

      <Entry Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
             Placeholder="Email" >
        <Entry.Behaviors>
          <local:EmailValidatorBehavior x:Name="emailValidator"/>
        </Entry.Behaviors>
      </Entry>

      <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Style="{Binding Source={x:Reference emailValidator}, 
                                Path=IsValid, 
                                Converter={StaticResource boolToStyleEmail}}" />

    </Grid>

  </StackLayout>
```

The code of `BooleanToObjectConverter.cs`

```
class BooleanToObjectConverter<T> : IValueConverter
{
    public T FalseObject { set; get; }

    public T TrueObject { set; get; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool)value ? this.TrueObject : this.FalseObject;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
                              object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((T)value).Equals(this.TrueObject);
    }
}
```

The code of `EmailValidatorBehavior.cs`

```
   public class EmailValidatorBehavior : Behavior<Entry>
    {
        const string emailRegex = @"^(?("")("".+?(?<!\\)""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))" +
            @"(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$";

        // Creating BindableProperties with Limited write access: http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=M%3AXamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValue(Xamarin.Forms.BindablePropertyKey%2CSystem.Object) 

        static readonly BindablePropertyKey IsValidPropertyKey = BindableProperty.CreateReadOnly("IsValid", typeof(bool), typeof(NumberValidatorBehavior), false);

        public static readonly BindableProperty IsValidProperty = IsValidPropertyKey.BindableProperty;

        public bool IsValid
        {
            get { return (bool)base.GetValue(IsValidProperty); }
            private set { base.SetValue(IsValidPropertyKey, value); }
        }

        protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry bindable)
        {
            bindable.TextChanged += HandleTextChanged;
        }


        void HandleTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            IsValid = (Regex.IsMatch(e.NewTextValue, emailRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250)));
            ((Entry)sender).TextColor = IsValid ? Color.Default : Color.Red;
        }

        protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry bindable)
        {
            bindable.TextChanged -= HandleTextChanged;

        }
    }
```

For more detail, you can check: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/behaviors-in-xamarin-forms/ .

**Updated:**

I don't think it's necessary to separate the property  `IsValid`   from the behavior and put it in the ViewModel. Excepet setting the style based on property `IsValid`  in the ValidatorBehavior, you can also set property `IsVisible` for your label based on the property  `IsValid`   from the behavior.

Please refer the following code:

```
 <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"   Text="please enter valid email" IsVisible="{Binding Source={x:Reference emailValidator}, 
                                Path=IsValid,Converter={StaticResource invertedBoolToBool}}"  TextColor="Red" />
```

**Note:**

1. `invertedBoolToBool` is a InverseBoolConverter

**InverseBoolConverter.cs**

```
public class InvertedBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !((bool)value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

2.add the following code in your ResourceDictionary of your page:

```
  <local1:InvertedBoolConverter x:Key="invertedBoolToBool" />
```

And there is also a sample in above article, you can check it here: https://github.com/nishanil/Xamarin.Forms-Samples .

Comment: See discussion in comments on question - I think they need to set an `EmailIsValid` property in their view model. If you can easily extend your answer to show how their page's XAML can bind the behavior's `IsValid` to page's BindingContext's `EmailIsValid` Property, that would be great. Otherwise, I'll make an answer for that part of the task.

Comment: Hi @AbanoubRefaat, have you checked my answer. I don't think it's necessary to separate the property  `IsValid `  from the behavior and put it in the ViewModel. Excepet set the style based on property `IsValid ` in the ValidatorBehavior, you can also set property `IsVisible` for your label based on the property  `IsValid `  from the behavior. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: I like how you set visibility directly from behavior's `IsValid`. But how make it so user can't continue, until **all** values are valid? Given that OP is using a view model, I was thinking `IsValid` should also set an equivalent property in view model. Then it is easy for other vm code to check that status.

Comment: Hi @AbanoubRefaat, any updates?